# Copying a Single Row From One Pandas Dataframe to Another Results in Missing Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to append the values from a single row in one Pandas dataframe to another. The two dataframes have the same number of rows, so I did not expect this to cause any issues. However, while it throws no errors, the output is problematic.

It results in the last two rows of the appended columns being `nan` values, and one of the values in the row being omitted in the process.

Here is the first dataframe `ds1':

```
+----+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|    | Unique ID |  Zip  |  Revenue  | Population | Revenue_Per_Person |
+----+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  1 |       179 | 75208 |  67789037 |      30171 |     2246.827649067 |
|  2 |       186 | 75208 |  62488032 |      30171 |    2071.1289649001 |
|  3 |       180 | 75212 | 107230739 |      24884 |    4309.2243610352 |
|  4 |       182 | 75212 |  81768596 |      24884 |    3285.9908374859 |
|  5 |       181 | 75137 |  93296769 |      18861 |    4946.5441386989 |
|  6 |       183 | 75237 |  79177044 |      17101 |    4629.9657329981 |
|  7 |       187 | 75237 |  60000000 |      17101 |    3508.5667504824 |
|  9 |       185 | 75236 |  76489996 |      15949 |    4795.9117186031 |
| 10 |       189 | 75236 |  55203335 |      15949 |    3461.2411436454 |
| 11 |       188 | 75115 |  57451134 |      48877 |     1175.422673241 |
+----+-----------+-------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

And the second, `ds2':

```
+---+-----------+-------+---------+
|   |     0     |   1   | cluster |
+---+-----------+-------+---------+
| 0 |  67789037 | 30171 |       1 |
| 1 |  62488032 | 30171 |       1 |
| 2 | 107230739 | 24884 |       0 |
| 3 |  81768596 | 24884 |       0 |
| 4 |  93296769 | 18861 |       0 |
| 5 |  79177044 | 17101 |       0 |
| 6 |  60000000 | 17101 |       1 |
| 7 |  76489996 | 15949 |       0 |
| 8 |  55203335 | 15949 |       1 |
| 9 |  57451134 | 48877 |       2 |
+---+-----------+-------+---------+
```

Here is my original code:

```
ds1['Type'] = ds2['cluster']
```

When I check the values of ds1 after running the above line, I get the following values in the `ds1` dataframe.

```
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------+
|    | Unique ID | Zip   | Revenue            | Population | Revenue_Per_Person | Type |
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------+
| 1  | 179       | 75208 | 67789037.0         | 30171      | 2246.827649066985  | 1.0  |
| 2  | 186       | 75208 | 62488032.0         | 30171      | 2071.1289649000696 | 0.0  |
| 3  | 180       | 75212 | 107230738.99999999 | 24884      | 4309.2243610352025 | 0.0  |
| 4  | 182       | 75212 | 81768596.0         | 24884      | 3285.9908374859347 | 0.0  |
| 5  | 181       | 75137 | 93296769.0         | 18861      | 4946.544138698902  | 0.0  |
| 6  | 183       | 75237 | 79177044.0         | 17101      | 4629.96573299807   | 1.0  |
| 7  | 187       | 75237 | 60000000.0         | 17101      | 3508.566750482428  | 0.0  |
| 9  | 185       | 75236 | 76489995.99999999  | 15949      | 4795.911718603046  | 2.0  |
| 10 | 189       | 75236 | 55203334.99999999  | 15949      | 3461.241143645369  | nan  |
| 11 | 188       | 75115 | 57451133.99999999  | 48877      | 1175.4226732409925 | nan  |
+----+-----------+-------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------+
```

It's interesting to note, that this code does throw the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

So I tried an alternative approach:

```
ds1['Type'] = ds2.loc[:,'cluster']
```

Which produces the same warning and the same dataframe outcome, with the single missing value and the two `nan` values at the end.

Comment: Pandas does intrinsic data alignment.  You have different indexes on each of the dataframe with the same length. One is a zero based the other starts with 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to `index` mis-alignment.  Notice that `ds1` has index values of `10` and `11` and you are assigning to a new column `ds1` a series without those indices.  That results in missing values for those two indices.

Assign the `values` from the right side to the column on the left to bypass the alignment issue.

```
ds1['Type'] = ds2['cluster'].values
```

---

If the index is meaningless to you, you could `reset_index` ahead of time

```
ds1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
ds2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

ds1['Type'] = ds2['cluster']
```